# SQL Server - Difference between errors 18456, 4064 and 4060

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I have a windows application written in vb.net. It interacts with SQL Server and we can create users from it on the server. From the application I disabled some users (it runs **DROP USER (loginName)** command behind the scenes). There was some strange behavior observed while handling `SqlException` in this case. While trying to login into SQL server (both through code and SQL server management studio) with disabled users, for some users it was giving a 4064 error code whereas for others it was giving 18456.

Here are some more details:

1. SQL Server version - **2016 SP1**. Mixed mode authentication.
2. There are a couple of DBs other than master.
3. On SQL Server in sys.syslogins table - For users for whom I got a 4064 error, the default DB was
   master. For those who's default DB was not master, I got 18456 error.
4. In code - For some reason, while catching `SqlException` in code, for
   users getting 4064 error while logging on SQL, I get 4060 error. For
   users with 18456 code, it works fine and I get the same error code in
   Exception.
5. Entries are in sys.syslogins, sys.sysusers table (as far as sys
   tables go).

As per the official description given:

[MSSQLSERVER_4064](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337282(v=sql.105).aspx):

> The SQL Server login was unable to connect because of a problem with its 
>   default database. Either the database itself is invalid or the login lacks 
>   CONNECT permission on the database.

and

[MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645917(v=sql.105).aspx):

> When a connection attempt is rejected because of an authentication failure that involves a bad password or user name, a message similar to the following is returned to the client: "Login failed for user ''. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)".

Could not find an official detailed description for 4060 except [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645613(v=sql.105).aspx):

> Cannot open database "%.*ls" requested by the login. The login failed.

Several forums say its related to login failure. I tried looking for some data on difference between nature of the failures for these 3 codes, but couldn't find one.

What are the scenarios in which we can get 4064 or 4060 codes? Are there any overlapping fail cases where we can get either of these (like for 18456 and 4060)?

**EDIT**: Here is the code for creating the connection:

```vb
connection = new SqlConnection()
Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder
builder.DataSource = "localhost"
builder.InitialCatalog = "DatabaseA"
builder.ConnectTimeout = 120
builder.UserID = username
builder.Password = Encrypt(password)
connection.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString
```

Comment: where is your code to connect?

Comment: Added the code.